# MVC4: making the area work for beginner

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-areas

I wanted to try and use area (just trying out). I added a area `foo` to my project: right click on the project then add area.
That folder contains sub folders where I can add controllers, view, models etc. It also has a cs file `fooAreaRegistration.cs` where routing for the area is done.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace AreasExample.Areas.foo
{
    public class fooAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "foo";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context )
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "foo_default",
                "foo/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new {controller = "Foo", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

`Global.asax` already has a function for registering area in app start

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
    }
}
```

I also then created a controller `Foo` which already has a default `Index` action, after that I added a view to the action. Based on the `context.MapRoute` in `fooAreaRegistration.cs`, if I run the program and go to this link `http://localhost:54421/foo/Foo` shouldn't it be working? 
It shows some error when I go to my area `foo` and controller `Foo`.
Error says

```
    Server Error in '/' Application.

    [A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast to 
[B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection. Type A originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. Type B originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.
```

Is there something I'm missing? Do I need to add something?

Edit: I'm not sure if I should delete this post as I found the answer which is mentioned as answer below. But then it may be helpful for those who are following the same book(ASP.NET MVC4 in action).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was probably because I downloaded the project of the book from internet which had older version of razor, and after I created an area in that project it couldn't cast it to the latest version of razor(i'm guessing) as the warning as in visual studio says:

```
  Warning   1   D:\Tutorial\mvc4ia-2012-06-


        13\src4\Chapter13\AreasExample\Areas\foo\Views\Foo\Index.cshtml: ASP.NET runtime error: 
        [A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast to 

        [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection. Type A originates from 
        'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
        PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 
        'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf385
        6ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. 
Type B originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf385
    6ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.   D:\Tutorial\mvc4ia-2012-06-
    13\src4\Chapter13\AreasExample\Areas\foo\Views\Foo\Index.cshtml AreasExample
```